# How to fetch one array value from the array?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have array like this

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
     [id] => 1930 [value] => 20)

  [1] => stdClass Object (

     [id] => 1931 [value] => 30 ) 

  [2] => stdClass Object ( 

     [id] => 1937 [value] => 30 ) 

  [3] => stdClass Object ( 

     [id] => 1938 [value] => 20 ) 
)
```

I want to fetch random array from this. The Id which has greater value(%) should be fetched more time (That value is %).

Comment: You should explain - *The pageId which has greater value(%)*

Comment: Yeah. The 1931 has 30 and others has 20.. etc.  Fetch should happen according to that value. The id 1931 should get more priority as it as 30%.

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried for that?

Comment: I just tried this array_rand($variable, 1); . But I don't know how to make it using priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = Array ( 
  (Object) array (id => 1930, value => 20),
  (Object) array (id => 1931, value => 30),
  (Object) array (id => 1937, value => 30),
  (Object) array (id => 1938, value => 20));

// count sum of all values
$sum = array_reduce($arr, function ($c, $i) { return $c += $i->value; }, 0);
// get random 
$rand = mt_rand(0, $sum);
echo $rand . "  ";
// select 1st item that sum of values >= random value
$new = array_filter($arr, function ($i) use (&$rand) { if($rand > 0 && ($rand -= $i->value) <= 0) return true; else return false; });
// change key to 0
$new = array_values($new);
echo  $new[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a another array and repeat the index of array for the number of times its value is and then fetch the values randomly this would do what you want

The above mentioned array would be

`array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to make a list of the cummulative sum of the values in the array, for instance if the values are 3, 1, and 2 the cummulative sums would be 3, 4 and 6. Then when you want to get a random element, you generate a random integer between 1 maximum sum, and then pick the element whose cumulative sum is largest of those whos cumulative sum is smaller than or equal to the random number. In that way, the chanse of any element being picked is proportional to its value.

So here is the setup, creating the cumulative sums:

```
var $cumsum = array();
var $sum = 0;
foreach($array as $obj) {
    $sum += $obj->value;
    array_push($cumsum, $sum);
}
var $maxsum = end($cumsum);
```

And here is the function actually picking an element:

```
function getRandomObject() {
    var $r = random(1, $max);
    if($r < $cumsum[0]) return $array[0];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cumsum); $i++)
        if($cumsum[$i]) > $r)
            return $array[$i--];
    return $array[$i];
}
```

**Disclaimar:** I have not tested this code, so don't expect it to run on a copy paste. Also, whatever code you use you should probably make sure it returns elements with the right probability using a monte carlo method.